# I need to convert a string data from byte to float

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, double

I have a text box and I need to convert the value I entered.

and in the end i guess i need to convert Double into a data.

but there is something wrong
example code:

```
textbox1.Text = "24.5";
double data = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);

byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes((data)f);
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
```

code working like this

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(22.3f);
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
```

how can i insert string data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can write

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes((data)f);
```

(data)f -> is not valid. I think you wanted to use it like 24.5f. Try to cast it into float. For example:

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes((float) data);
```

Furthermore why would you parse a string as an int into a double? Parse the string directly as double.

Look at @Joel Coehoorn comment.
For more information about Double.TryParse() look at: [Microsofts handbook about Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 3):

`int.Parse()` is wrong and will likely throw an exception. If you have the string value `"24.5"`, what do you expect an **integer** to do with the ".5" portion?

Try this:

```
textbox1.Text = "24.5";
double data = double.Parse(textbox1.Text);
```

Even better if you use one of the [`double.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0) overloads.